# storing images in iphone application

Tags: iphone, database, image, storage

im making an application that store multipe information like name description images for each entity. ( large number of entity). I have an issue in storing images in for this application. whats the best way to store them. database or document directory. and also im affraid that the images will increase the size of my application. waiting for your advises. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binary data, use a file bases approach. If you want to manage them with a database (i.e. Core Data), just store the filenames and any meta data you want to handle in the database.

Comment: the problem is im storing large number of images . wouldnt that affect the  size of the app if i store them in ressources file

Comment: You either store them in files or in a database - so the images will take their size somewhere. The total size won't be smaller when including them in a database. It's just that a database is the wrong place for them.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports blobs. I don't know the wisdom of using it as an actual store for image data--I imagine its performance would depend a lot on the real world particulars of your usage--but it's an option.